# Running npm script on windows starting with a period

Tags: windows, npm, devops

I have a `package.json` file with the following script defined:

`"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/selenium-cucumber-js/index.js"
  }`

When I run `npm test` on linux or mac this script runs as expected. On Windows however I get an error:

`/node_modules/selenium-cucumber-js/index.js
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.`

However if I run the command `./node_modules/selenium-cucumber-js/index.js` directly from a cmd prompt it works correctly. The same issue also occurs if I try to run any other script through npm that starts with a ".". I haven't been able to find any other thread talking about this as an issue.

I am running npm versions `5.6.0` on Windows 10 Home.

Does anyone know how I can get this working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything defined under `scripts` gets executed in the default system shell and on Windows `./node_modules/selenium-cucumber-js/index.js` is definitely not a valid command (or rather a path). It just happens that the same file has a `+x` argument and a shebang pointing to a `Node.js` (or another JS interpreter) binary so that it gets executed on Linux without intervention.

I'm quite certain you'll get the same error if you were to execute the same command in the default Windows shell (`cmd.exe`) but you may get away with it in some ports/emulations of *nix shells (i.e. Cygwin, MSYS, bash.exe etc.) which may give you a false sense of everything working correctly outside of the `npm` chain.

If you want to make sure your script gets executed by `Node.js` while using relative paths and keeping cross-platform compatibility, call it explicitly as:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node ./node_modules/selenium-cucumber-js/index.js"
}
```

This will also take care of things like not having a proper `x` flag or shebang in the script you're executing and since `Node.js` is perfectly comfortable with using *nix paths on Windows it won't complain either.

Comment: Thanks @zwer, great answer.

Answer (score 14):

Since npm 5.1

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

or (64bit installation)

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

Note that you need to have [git for windows installed](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

You can revert it by running:
npm config delete script-shell

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you write a shell script, you need to specify which shell it is written for. For inline `package.json` scripts, you should do this in an `.npmrc` alongside your `package.json`, like this:

```
script-shell = bash
```

If you don't specify a shell, `npm` is free to pick any old shell. On Windows, it picks `cmd.exe`, which is almost never what you want.

(Note: I don't recommend using `npm config set` for this. It sets local user configuration. The correct shell should be stored in version control alongside your scripts.)